# How to block ajax URL to PHP script after AJAX success?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have some line code AJAX in WordPress, I want AJAX URL don't affect into PHP action.

Code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.load-article', function() {
   var reply_id = $(this).attr('data-reply-id');
   var data_child = {
      action: 'ajax_child_reply',
      post_id: reply_id,
   }
   $.ajax({
      url: ajaxurl,
      data: data_child,
      success: function(response) {
         console.log(response);
      }
   });
});
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_child_reply', 'ajax_child_reply');

function ajax_child_reply() {
   $post_id = esc_attr($_POST['post_id']);
   // to much code...
   $data_child = array('delete_url' => '<a href="'.$delete_url.
      '">Delete</a>', );
   wp_send_json($data_child);
}
```

Now, on **`href`** deleted link after ajax success, every link have **`href=".../wp-admin-ajax.php/http://delete_link"`**

How to remove affected AJAX URL in PHP script?
Thank you.

Comment: That is unclear. I don't get the relation between your Ajax request and the `href` of an unmentionned link... Please clarify your question by posting the relevant HTML (about the link, for example) and be more specific about what you wish to be deleted or whatever.

Comment: where you assign the value for `$delete_url`?

Comment: In php ->  // to much code...

Comment: `$data_child = array('delete_url' => '<a href="'.$delete_url.` etc. This line appends the value of `$delete_url` to a link that it generates and sends back to the client. So that's where the value is coming from. It only seems to generate one link though (unless your sample is missing a loop or something), and the ajax code that you've shown doesn't actually do anything with that data except log it to the console. So the exact nature of your problem is still unclear. You also haven't said what you want it to do instead.